# How to change font colors with termcolor

Tags: python, termcolor

When i'm using module termcolor for change color of font

```
from termcolor import colored
print(colored(" THIS APPLICATION IS DEVELOPED BY : ",'yellow'),colored("Mr KATIB Rabah",'red'))
print(" --------------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

in the command prompt Symbols appear without changing colors The opposite of what Pycharm shows

```
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19041.508]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.
C:\Users\Katib>cd PycharmProjects\pythonProject

C:\Users\Katib\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>python test6.py
←[33m THIS APPLICATION IS DEVELOPED BY : ←[0m ←[31mMr KATIB Rabah←[0m
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [Pycharm show this with colors][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcOQg.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [How to print colored text in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python)

To get colors working in Windows, you need to run `os.system("color")` first.

```
import os
from termcolor import colored

os.system("color")
print(colored(" THIS APPLICATION IS DEVELOPED BY : ",'yellow'),colored("Mr KATIB Rabah",'red'))
```